# Grouped bar chart in R without Y variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I want to create a grouped bar chart with the x variable being 'satisfied', grouped by 'HealthyFd'.
The satisfied variable is how satisfied people are with life and is numeric from 1-10. The HealthyFd variable is how often people have been unable to buy healthy food. This has the categories 'often true', 'sometimes true' and 'never true'.
Therefore, the y axis would be the counts in each group and not another variable. I am using ggplot2.

I have tried the following code:

```
ggplot(data = food, aes(fill = HealthyFd, x=satisfied)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity"))
```

But get the following error:

```
Error: geom_bar requires the following missing aesthetics: y
```

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `geom_bar(..., stat = "identity")` is the same as `geom_col()`. To have ggplot2 do the counting for you, you should use `geom_bar()` without `stat = "identity"`, or `geom_bar(..., stat = "count")`, which is the default. The default `y` aesthetic for `geom_bar()` is `after_stat(count)`, which is a computed variable; so that is why it is complaining that it is missing.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much!